# can I play the same game but on two different play disks on xbox 360

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I'm not sure how to say this but I used a friend of mine's grand theft auto v and I installed it and everything but I'm going to buy my own grand theft auto v soon but I would like to know if I can use my play disk to continue my story mode or do I need my friend's disk?

Answer (score 3):

Nothing is tied to the specific game disc on either the PS3 or Xbox 360 as far as I'm aware. You didn't specify which system. You could start a game on a Redbox rental for instance, and then continue it on a purchased game. As long as you have the save game data still, it should work.